# First element in a list haskell

Tags: haskell

So i need to do a find2 method that take the first Element out.

For example `find2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a`

and `find2 (>4) [1 .. 10]`

Should have a the output `5`

I am not good with haskell, but i want to learn it.

My first try was

```
find2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
find2 p [] = []
find2 p (x:xs)
 |p x = x+1
 |otherwise = finde p xs
```

but i am getting an error

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[a0]'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          find2 :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
        at C:\\Users\XY\Desctop\XY.hs:30:1-32
    * In the expression: []
      In an equation for `find2': find2 p [] = []
    * Relevant bindings include
        p :: a -> Bool
          (bound at C:\\Users\XY\Desctop\XY.hs:31:7)
        find2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
          (bound at C:\\Users\XY\Desctop\XY.hs:31:1)
```

Comment: What is `finde`?

Comment: And now you know why that type signature is a lie: if no element in the list matches the predicate, you can't return an element that matches the predicate. You might like to return a `Maybe a` or `[a]` instead to indicate that the number of matches is not statically known.

Comment: One thing to recognize is that `find2 p = head . filter p`; you find *all* the elements that satisfy `p`, but only (try to) return the first one. Part of learning Haskell is learning to think in terms of *what* you want, rather than low-level descriptions of *how* to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a problem here. There *might* not be a value in your list for which p holds true. You can see that problem in the base case of your function, when you return an empty list. However, you declared your function to return a single `a` value, and not a list.

Because of that, you need a way to differentiate a found value from an empty value. For this you can declare your function to return `Maybe a` instead of `a`. That way, when you reach the empty list case, you can return `Nothing`, and if you find the element you were looking for you can return `Just x`. It would look like this:

```
find2 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find2 p [] = Nothing
find2 p (x:xs)
 |p x = Just x
 |otherwise = find2 p xs
```

If you're not familiar with the `Maybe` type, you can read more about it [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe)

Answer (score 3):

If you're ok with erroring when the list contains no satisfactory elements, you can do this:

```
find p xs = head (filter p xs)
```

or the equivalent point-free, which I like more

```
find p = head . filter p
```

(not this though, it's over the top)

```
find = (head .) . filter -- obscure, not a good choice
```

If you want to return it in a `Maybe`, you can import `Data.Maybe` and do this:

```
find p = listToMaybe . filter p
```

If you want it in a list, this never errors:

```
find p = take 1 . filter p
```

You can use `dropWhile (not . p)` instead of `filter p` if you like, too.

Manually defining the recursion is fine too, but I think it's work that isn't necessary.